# kafka connect 100% cpu

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka_2.12-2.3.1 on ubuntu 18 with JDK 13. While everything is working fine, I noticed that Kafka connect is consuming 100% cpu. Even though there are no messages to process it is continuing to consume cpu.

Took threaddump but there are no clues in it.

I am using **Postgres-connector** with Postgre 11.X. Also I am starting **Kafka connect in distributed mode**.

**UPDATE 1**

After searching through various sites, I got few hints and realised that it could be a bug in JDK itself (caused by polling). I saw a section of Thread dump which was highlighted by most

I will check the behavior with Standalone kafka connect.

```
"KafkaBasedLog Work Thread - connect-offsets" #31 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=828.02ms elapsed=1039.24s tid=0x00007f8530089800 nid=0x305b runnable  [0x00007f852a3f4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@13.0.1/Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@13.0.1/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@13.0.1/SelectorImpl.java:124)
        - locked <0x00000000809efd98> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000000809efd40> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@13.0.1/SelectorImpl.java:136)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:794)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:467)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:262)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1281)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1225)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.poll(KafkaBasedLog.java:262)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.access$500(KafkaBasedLog.java:71)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog$WorkThread.run(KafkaBasedLog.java:337)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Tried standalone mode and the CPU is still topping to 100%. I confirm that there are no messages for processing.

Comment: Which connector do you use? Jdbc or Debezium? Can you include your configs? Plus, Kafka doesn't support JDK 13 yet

Comment: @cricket_007 Added connector details,

Comment: Have you tried using a different JDK or editing any of the consumer settings in Connect related to polling?

Comment: @cricket_007, no I haven't. I will try standalone mode and update the results.

Comment: why not tryout with jdk8?

Comment: @ravi I have seen few posts which indicate that people are facing this problem with JDK9+. I will give a try to jdk8, but it will take a while.

Comment: I understand that this question is quite old, but I'm facing the same problem with the latest kafka on openjdk 1.8.0_232. Have you found the root of the problem?

Comment: @Ayzen, I couldn't try with JDK 8 due to EOL and we are still having this issue.